# Do you get the extra attack from a Haste spell you cast on yourself with 1 round duration?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, duration

A rogue PC in my campaign has just picked up the Trapsmith prestige class and gained spellcasting this way. He picked *Haste* as one of his first spells.

Now I wonder: His current caster level is 1. If he casts *haste*, how long does it last?

Only the round he casts the spell? Then he would only benefit from increased speed (+30 feet or double, whichever is lower) and +1 dodge to Reflex and AC until his next turn.

Or could he transfer the benefit to the next round, if he takes his move action first and then casts the spell with the standard action?

Comment: Related: [When do spells expire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35108/8610)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106233/discussion-on-question-by-giorin-do-you-get-the-extra-attack-from-a-haste-spell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In your case you don't

Not that it's impossible to get the extra attack, it's just that you need a full round action to do so, and Haste would only last 1 round in your case.

*Haste* states:

> When making a **full attack action**, a hasted creature may make one extra
> attack with any weapon he is holding.

If you were a *Factotum* with the *Cunning Surge* ability:

> (Ex): Starting at 8th level, you learn to push yourself when needed. By spending 3 inspiration points, you can take an extra standard action during your turn.

You could use your extra standard action to cast haste and then use your full-round action to attack and get the extra attack.

Using it on someone else would grant way more benefits since the spell will end when your next turn begins.

## Sidenote:

At first level it is not very useful on yourself that's for sure, but if you had a *Chameleon* ally in the party he would **greatly** like to make a scroll with your help and write it in his spellbook (1  level dip of wizard for the *Chameleon* is kind of required though) to learn the spell for himself as a level 1 spell.