# When do spells (which do not specify end or start of turn) expire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

When casting spells with a duration longer than instantaneous, at what point in the round does the effect expire?

Say, for example, you cast a spell with a duration of 1 round. Does that mean the spell ends at the end of your turn? Or at the beginning of your next turn?

...which, yes, is the exact same question as [another](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35108/when-do-spells-expire) already on the site, but I'm asking for a rule to cite in 5e. I'll add the fact that while 1 round spells specify whether the effect lasts until the start or end of the next turn, longer duration spells tend not to. This can be important for, for example, deciding if a spell such as *aura of vitality* can have its bonus action effect used 10, or 11 times before the duration expires.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate as it has been asked before. This is okay, duplicates can make questions easier to find.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I appreciate it, actually, since I couldn't find it! I was searching for -spell- durations specifically but didn't think to go one step up and be more general.

Comment: I've added the duration tag to one of the other dupes, might help.